# Searching for a string within a string of strings

Tags: swift, string, validation

so I have created an array or all the information from my database and set it to a large string that contains individual smaller strings. I want to create a statement that essentially validates it and says if the string is inside the string of strings, pop up an alert. I just can't seem to create a correct statement that does so.

below is my code that creates the large string and is named userInfo

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  WagerMe
//
//  Created by Christopher calvert on 3/1/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Christopher calvert. All rights reserved.
// CODED BY CHRIS CALVERT

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var userInfo = [[String]]()



    @IBOutlet weak var fullname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userAge: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPassword: UITextField!

    @IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {
        let stuff = userInfo

        if(fullname.text!.isEmpty || userAge.text!.isEmpty || userUsername.text!.isEmpty || userEmail.text!.isEmpty || userPassword.text!.isEmpty) {

            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "All fields are required to register.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return;
        }

        func validateAlpha(field: [String]) -> Bool {
            let alphanumericChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "!@#$%^&*()-_=+1234567890.,")

            var result = false
            for x in field {
                if (x.rangeOfCharacter(from: alphanumericChars as CharacterSet) != nil) {
                    result = true
                }
                else {
                    result = false
                }
            }
            return result
        }

        func validateAge(field: [String]) -> Bool {
            let alphanumericChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "!@#$%^&*()-_=+.,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

            var result = false
            for x in field {
                if (x.rangeOfCharacter(from: alphanumericChars as CharacterSet) != nil) {
                    result = true
                }
                else {
                    result = false
                }
            }
            return result
        }

        func validateEmail(field: [String]) -> Bool {
            let alphanumericChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "!#$%^&*()-_=+,")

            var result = false
            for x in field {
                if (x.rangeOfCharacter(from: alphanumericChars as CharacterSet) != nil) {
                    result = true
                }
                else {
                    result = false
                }
            }
            return result
        }

        func validate(field: [String]) -> Bool {
            let alphanumericChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "!@#$%^&*()-_=+")

            var result = false

            for x in field {
                if (x.rangeOfCharacter(from: alphanumericChars as CharacterSet) != nil) {
                    result = true
                }
                else {
                    result = false
                }
            }
            return result
        }



        if validateAlpha(field: [fullname.text!]) {
            let validateName = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You have entered invalid characters in the 'Name' field", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            validateName.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(validateName, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if validateAge(field: [userAge.text!]) {
            let validateAge = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You have entered non-numbers in the 'Age' field", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            validateAge.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(validateAge, animated: true, completion: nil)



        } else if validate(field: [userUsername.text!]) {
            let validateUsername = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You have entered invalid characters in the 'Username' field", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            validateUsername.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(validateUsername, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if validateEmail(field: [userEmail.text!]) {
            let validateEmail = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You have entered invalid characters in the 'Email' field", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            validateEmail.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(validateEmail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if validate(field: [userPassword.text!]) {
            let validatePassword = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You have entered invalid characters in your password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            validatePassword.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(validatePassword, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if (fullname.text?.characters.count)! > 31 {
            let nameTooLong = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your name must be less than 30 characters.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            nameTooLong.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(nameTooLong, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if (fullname.text?.characters.count)! < 5 {
            let nameTooShort = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your name must be greater than 4 characters.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            nameTooShort.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(nameTooShort, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if (userPassword.text?.characters.count)! < 5 {
            let passwordTooShort = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your password must be greater than 4 characters.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            passwordTooShort.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(passwordTooShort, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if (userPassword.text?.characters.count)! > 19 {
            let passwordTooLong = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your password must be less than 18 characters.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            passwordTooLong.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(passwordTooLong, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if (userAge.text?.characters.count)! < 2 {
            let passwordTooLong = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Sorry! You're not old enough to register for WagerMe.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            passwordTooLong.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(passwordTooLong, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if (userUsername.text?.characters.count)! > 21 {
            let usernameTooLong = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your username must be less than 20 characters.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            usernameTooLong.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(usernameTooLong, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if (userUsername.text?.characters.count)! < 5 {
            let usernameTooShort = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your username must be greater than 4 characters.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            usernameTooShort.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(usernameTooShort, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {




            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team10/store.php")! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            let postString = "a=\(fullname.text!)&b=\(userAge.text!)&c=\(userUsername.text!)&d=\(userEmail.text!)&e=\(userPassword.text!)"

            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }

                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            }

            task.resume()
        }
        //Alert for successful registration

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "User", message: "User successfully registered!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        fullname.text = ""
        userAge.text = ""
        userEmail.text = ""
        userUsername.text = ""
        userPassword.text = ""


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string:"http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team10/pullUsers.php")
        do {
            let userdata = try Data(contentsOf: url!)

            let users = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: userdata, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
            if let jsonarray = users["users"] as? NSArray{
                for index in 0...jsonarray.count-1{
                    var array = [String]()
                    let object = jsonarray[index] as! [String : AnyObject]
                    let username = object["username"] as! String
                    let email = object["email"] as! String


                    array.append(username)
                    array.append(email)
                    userInfo.append(array)
                }


            }
        }
        catch{
        }
        print(userInfo)

        //Looks for single or multiple taps.
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.dismissKeyboard))

        //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
        //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
    }



}
```

my creation of the array and setting it to a string of string starts in the ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

After investigation of the code I can suggest you to create `struct` that will represent users.

It is because of the response that is received from :

```
http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team10/pullUsers.php
```

That is :

> {"users":[{"username":"sspoulos","email":"sspoulos@yahoo.com"},{"username":"ctcalver","email":"ctcalver@indiana.edu"},{"username":"zjhabib","email":"zjhabib@indiana.edu"},{"username":"aukmoore","email":"aukmoore@indiana.edu"},{"username":"tester","email":"tester"},{"username":"austin","email":"email"},{"username":"zane","email":"zane"},{"username":"kbryant","email":"kbryant@indiana.edu"},{"username":"rartest","email":"rartest@indiana.edu"},{"username":"assman","email":"assman@yahoo.com"},{"username":"tromo","email":"tromo@indiana.edu"},{"username":"emanning","email":"emanning@indiana.edu"},{"username":"steventest","email":"steventest"},{"username":"hsimpson","email":"hsimpson@indiana.edu"},{"username":"pgriffin","email":"pgriffin@indiana.edu"},{"username":"abelinc","email":"abelinc@indiana.edu"},{"username":"akmoore","email":"akmoore20@indiana.edu"}]}

Example:

```
struct User {
    let username: String
    let email: String
}
```

After this you going to create User array instead of the huge string. That will give you opportunity to validate, filter data in the way you would like and with clear syntax.

Example of validation if user is in array:

```
let users = [User(name: "sspoulos", email: "sspoulos@yahoo.com"),User(name: "ctcalver", email: "ctcalver@indiana.edu"),User(name: "zjhabib", email: "zjhabib@indiana.edu"),User(name: "aukmoore", email: "aukmoore@indiana.edu")]


let result = users.contains{$0.name == "sspoulos"}
```

In this way you going to know if user is presented in the array and if not show alert.